# Plotly - How to highlight two results from two figures in the same plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm using plotly with Python version 3, and I have a plot with two lines as different figures like this [image: picture]. I would like to highlight in the same moment with my mouse both values in the plot under and up! My code is below:

```
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=df.date,
    y=df.price,
    name='Volume',
    line=dict(
        color='rgb(205, 12, 24)',
        width=4)
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df.date,
    y=df.sentiment,
    name='Sentiment',
    mode='lines+markers',
    line=dict(
        color='rgb(22, 96, 167)',
        width=4)
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(trace0, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 2, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=800, title='Sentiment Analysis on Social Media')
py.plot(fig, filename='simple-subplot-with-annotations')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)" onwards with the below

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go    
data = [trace0, trace1]  
layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'Sentiment Analysis on Social Media')
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
py.plot(fig, filename='simple-subplot-with-annotations.html')
```

Comment: I was already able to do this. The two plot (if it is possible) should have their own y scale. I would like to have the two plots as showed, but highlight both values in the same time.